# why the crictl command did not list the images

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

when I tried to use crictl to list all images like this in Debian 12:

```
root@k8sslave01:/etc# crictl images
IMAGE               TAG                 IMAGE ID            SIZE
```

did not show any images. the ctr list works fine:

```
root@k8sslave01:/etc# ctr images list
REF                                                           TYPE                                                      DIGEST                                                                  SIZE      PLATFORMS                                                                    LABELS
registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6 application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json sha256:3d380ca8864549e74af4b29c10f9cb0956236dfb01c40ca076fb6c37253234db 294.7 KiB linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64,linux/ppc64le,linux/s390x,windows/amd64 -
registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6                                     application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json      sha256:8a9b8e25874aac2f58bc7d523e55c4a98f03653d109f3acc77cd064544f906f4 290.9 KiB linux/amd64
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the /etc/crictl.yaml config:

```
root@k8sslave01:/etc# cat /etc/crictl.yaml
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 10
#debug: true
debug: false
```

I have already tried to import the images like this:

```
root@k8sslave01:~# ctr image import /root/pause.tar --all-platforms
unpacking registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6 (sha256:8a9b8e25874aac2f58bc7d523e55c4a98f03653d109f3acc77cd064544f906f4)...done
```

still could not show by crictl command.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the crictl default namespaces in k8s.io, when import images, we should specify the namespaces like this:

```
ctr -n=k8s.io image import /root/pause.tar
```